# To get total count based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, tableau-api

I am struggling to get the count of a particular person. As I am new to tableau I don't know how to write the condition for this query.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt 
FROM 
  Expert_CollaborationsRequests 
WHERE 
  ExpertID=3 AND 
  IsAccepted = 1
```

Comment: Your query looks good. Please share some example data and the expected result.

Comment: Share the schema of the table Expert_CollaborationsRequests. The query looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(ExpertID),COUNT(IsAccepted ) as cnt 
FROM 
  Expert_CollaborationsRequests 
WHERE 
  ExpertID=3 OR 
  IsAccepted = 1
```

Comment: I need to put this as calculation in tableau

Comment: please explain your answer.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I am a beginner here and next time i will careful. thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a calculated field as:

Calculation1: `IF ExpertID=3 AND IsAccepted = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Then, place this field on a shelf (row, columns, etc.) and select `Measure (Sum)`.

Comment: ok thanks Armin, help me to find out this.... this is for particular user but I have 1000 users and I have to get the count of each user. And in IsAccepted column I have values as 0 and 1 and I should filter the 0 and display it

Answer (score 0):

You can use LOD (Level of Detail) like so:

```
{ FIXED [ExpertID]: SUM(IF [IsAccepted]= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) }
```

This will give you aggregated values for each user.
For more information on LOD, please follow official Tableau help link [here](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.htm)